# Accessing group child for rollover in three.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js, parent-child

So I have a raycaster in three.js that allows me to detect when my group is rolled over. It currently works so that when I mouse over any child of the group, the entire group's material changes.
Here's my question : how can I detect which specific child was rolled over and highlight only that specific child ?

Here's the code :

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(tiles_group.children, true);

if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
  intersectedObject = intersects[0].object;        
  intersectedObject.material.emissive.setHex( 0xffffff );      
  intersected = true;      
} else {
  intersected = false;}
```

This should be easy but after hours of searching and trying I can't seem to find the proper logic/syntax. Thanks in advance to anyone reading/replying to this post !

Comment: Are the objects sharing the same material? That would cause the symptoms you are seeing.

Comment: Indeed they were ! I put my material variable declaration inside my object adding loop and voila ! It's working perfectly ! I should have remembered that. Once again, thanks a lot WestLangley, you rock !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHORT ANSWER : create one material per object instead of one material for all of them

EXPLANATION : As WestLangley pointed out, I just needed to create a separate material for each child object instead of having them all share the same material, ie putting the material creation INSIDE the loop used to generate the objects so that every object gets its own material. This way, material is changed individually for each object.

Comment: You are a legend. Didn't think this was a referencing issue!